# Avoid gaps when using geom_path with colour bin values that are factors in R

Tags: r

I'm trying to plot some lines from xy data using `geom_path` and hex values for colour. When I use numeric data for assigning colour (bins) the plotting is continuous but gaps appear between each colour if the colour vars are factors (bins1). How do I use the colour values in bins1 without the gaps? Below is a reproducible example -

Sample data:

```
test <- structure(list(x = c(0, 0.57, 0.43, -0.65, -2.27, -3.5, -3.39, 
                         -1.5, 1.75, 5.12, 7.01, 6.21, 2.55, -2.87, -7.97, -10.51, -9.02, 
                         -3.59, 4, 10.84, 14.01, 11.82, 4.61, -5.14, -13.71, -17.51, -14.6, 
                         -5.62, 6.31, 16.6, 21.01, 17.38, 6.61, -7.48, -19.49, -24.51, 
                         -20.15, -7.58, 8.68, 22.39, 28.02, 22.91, 8.54, -9.88, -25.31, 
                         -31.52, -25.65, -9.48, 11.11, 28.23, 35.02, 28.39, 10.41, -12.35, 
                         -31.16, -38.52, -31.12, -11.32, 13.6, 34.1, 42.01, 33.84, 12.21, 
                         -14.87, -37.05, -45.51, -36.55, -13.09, 16.16, 40, 49.01, 39.24, 
                         13.96, -17.46, -42.97, -52.51, -41.93, -14.8, 18.78, 45.95, 56, 
                         44.6, 15.64, -20.11, -48.93, -59.5, -47.27, -16.45, 21.45, 51.93, 
                         62.99, 49.93, 17.25, -22.82, -54.93, -66.48, -52.57, -18.04, 
                         24.19, 57.94),
                   y = c(0, 0.41, 1.33, 2, 1.64, -0.01, -2.48, -4.67, 
                         -5.32, -3.68, 0.03, 4.56, 8.01, 8.64, 5.71, -0.07, -6.66, -11.36, 
                         -11.96, -7.73, 0.13, 8.76, 14.71, 15.27, 9.73, -0.21, -10.88, 
                         -18.06, -18.57, -11.72, 0.3, 13.02, 21.42, 21.87, 13.69, -0.4, 
                         -15.17, -24.79, -25.17, -15.65, 0.53, 17.33, 28.16, 28.45, 17.6, 
                         -0.67, -19.5, -31.53, -31.74, -19.53, 0.82, 21.69, 34.91, 35.01, 
                         21.45, -0.99, -23.88, -38.29, -38.29, -23.36, 1.18, 26.1, 41.68, 
                         41.55, 25.25, -1.39, -28.32, -45.07, -44.81, -27.13, 1.61, 30.56, 
                         48.47, 48.07, 29, -1.85, -32.81, -51.87, -51.31, -30.85, 2.1, 
                         35.07, 55.27, 54.56, 32.68, -2.37, -37.35, -58.68, -57.79, -34.51, 
                         2.66, 39.64, 62.1, 61.02, 36.32, -2.97, -41.94, -65.51, -64.25, 
                         -38.11),
                   bins = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L,
                            1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
                            2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
                            2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
                            3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
                            3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
                            3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L),
                   bins1 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                       2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
                                       2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
                                       2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
                                       3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
                                       3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
                                       3L, 3L, 3L),
                                     levels = c("#f6f9e0", "#f1f7b8", "#fffe48", "#fafa43", 
                                                "#f6e024", "#e2c207", "#d7a221", "#ff8915", "#ff6915", "#f94747", 
                                                "#cf2424", "#8b0d0d"), 
                                     class = "factor")), 
              row.names = c(NA, 100L), class = "data.frame")
```

Plot with gaps:

```
ggplot(test, aes(x, y)) + 
  geom_path(aes(colour = bins1)) +
  coord_cartesian() +
  theme(panel.grid.major=element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor=element_blank(),
        panel.background=element_blank(),
        legend.position="none",
        axis.title.x=element_blank(),
        axis.text.x=element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.x=element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.y=element_blank(),
        axis.text.y=element_blank(),
        axis.title.y=element_blank())
```

I tried this option also but the problem persisted:

```
colour_list <- c("#f6f9e0", "#f1f7b8", "#fffe48", "#fafa43", 
             "#f6e024", "#e2c207", "#d7a221", "#ff8915", 
             "#ff6915", "#f94747", "#cf2424", "#8b0d0d")

geom_path(aes(colour = I(colour_list[bins])))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not elegant, but the solution I came up with was to add an extra row at the end of each bin and populate it with the next row's xy and the previous row's bin number and hex value:

Add row when value changes in column
test <- do.call(rbind, by(test, test$bins, rbind, NA))
Remove last row

```
test <- test[1:nrow(test)-1,]
```

Reset rownames

```
rownames(test) <- NULL
```

Add xy data from start row of next bin to the NA rows

```
test[which(is.na(test[,1])),1:2] <- test[which(is.na(test[,1]))+1,1:2]
```

Add bin and hex values from previous rows to the NA rows

```
test[which(is.na(test[,3])),3:4] <- test[which(is.na(test[,3]))-1,3:4]
```

Run `ggplot` again and the gaps will be filled.